# Plotting multiple wordcloud (ggwordcloud) with other types of plots in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, word-cloud

I am trying to plot several wordclouds in a scatterplot and I wonder if one can control the position of a wordcloud in ggplot?
As an example the code below overlays both wordclouds around the origin of the plot.
Say I want to place the second wordcloud at x=4 and y =35. Is that possible?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggwordcloud)

ggplot() +
geom_point(mtcars,mapping=aes(wt,mpg)) +
geom_text_wordcloud(love_words_small,mapping=aes(label=word)) +
geom_text_wordcloud(mtcars,mapping=aes(label=rownames(mtcars))) +
theme_minimal()
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for the exact same thing. Looks like you can simply add the x and y aesthetic arguments. Ie.

```
ggplot() +
geom_point(mtcars,mapping=aes(wt,mpg)) +
geom_text_wordcloud(love_words_small,mapping=aes(label=word)) +
geom_text_wordcloud(mtcars,mapping=aes(label=rownames(mtcars), x=4,y=35)) +
theme_minimal()
```

What I did may be more generally helpful for folks, which is to pass x and y vectors:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggwordcloud)
ggplot(data = mtcars %>% mutate(car_names = rownames(mtcars)) %>% 
              group_by(cyl), 
       mapping = aes(label=car_names, x=mpg, y=disp)) +
  geom_text_wordcloud()
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could save the wordclouds as separate plots, and then add them to one plot with `cowplot` or `gridExtra` or any of the packages that lets you combine plots?